# How to access IPFS for NFT storage giving out authentication 401 error

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, ipfs, nft

I'm building a simple NFT minter dapp, the images are not being uploaded to IPFS storage while using Web3.storage, despite using my secret project ID and key[image: authentication error]

I tried creating a different project ID and key to access the IPFS storage yet still gets the unauthorised response